# How could I find the vector potential in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

In a physics problem I'm asked to find the vector potential $\vec{A}$ given that magnetic field is $\vec{B}=\dfrac{k \mu_0 s^3}{4}\hat{\phi}$ where $k$ and $\mu_0$ are constants.

I know that $\nabla \times \vec{A}=\vec{B}$.
So when I unravel the operator,

$\dfrac{1}{s}\dfrac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial \phi}=\dfrac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial z}$,
$\dfrac{\partial A_s}{\partial z}-\dfrac{\partial A_z}{\partial s}=\dfrac{k \mu_0 s^3}{4}$, $\dfrac{\partial A_s}{\partial \phi}=\dfrac{\partial (sA_{\phi})}{\partial s}$.

As you could see, I'm not sure what to do from here.  Also, I am given the current per unit area $\vec{J}=ks^2\hat{z}$ where I could find $\vec{A}$ from $\nabla^2 \vec{A}=-\mu_0\vec{J}$, but I think it's an even messier route. Any instructions on how to proceed or an easier method to find $\vec{A}$ are appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your coordinate system?  I know what cylindrical coordinates are, but what is $s$ is your notation?  Thanks!

Comment: I glean $s$ is the radial coordinate, but I'm not sure . . . is this correct?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, s is the radial coordinate.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!  Thinking . . .

Comment: Then $\phi$ is the angular variable, so $s^{-1} \hat \phi$ ($=s^{-1} (\partial/\partial \phi)$ in differential-topologial notation) is the *unit* vector field tangent to the circles of constant $s$?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint:

Note first that the solution $\vec{A}$ that you seek is defined only up to an additive gradient. In other words, if $\vec{A}$ is a solution to your problem, then so is $\vec{A}' = \vec{A} + \nabla\xi$, where $\xi = \xi(s, \phi, z )$ is differentiable once. This is true because $\nabla \times \nabla\xi = 0$.

These represent a family of vector potentials that result in the same physical field $\vec{B}$ on taking the curl (gauge invariance). You're basically at complete liberty to choose any $\xi$ you please as long as its first derivative exists. Substitute the expression for $\vec{A}'$ into the 3 equations you obtained from the curl, and make intelligent choices for the partial derivatives of $\xi$. You should end up with a system of PDEs that are easier to solve than the extremely complex ones that the original curl gave you.

I worked through it and got:
$$
\vec{A} = \left[ -\frac{k\mu_0 s^4}{16} + f(z) \right] \hat{z}
$$

where $f(z)$ is any function of $z$. You can even toss it away if you like!

Comment: So for the components of $\vec{A}$, I'd replace it with $\vec{A'}$?

Comment: Yes...because you are guaranteed that both will return the same field $\vec{B}$, which is where all the basic physics lies.

Comment: Could you explain the difference in sign between $\vec{B}$ and $\nabla \times A$?

Comment: I'm sorry, my original answer had a typo. There should indeed be a negative sign. I've edited it now. Thanks!

Comment: Do I substitute $\vec{A'}-\nabla\xi$ for $\vec{A}$? Or do I perform $\nabla \times \vec{A'}$?

Comment: The two options equivalent. You need to ensure that the gauge function $\xi$ is a part of your system of equations. Like I said, $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{A}'$ are physically completely equivalent.

Comment: If you're interested in a broad-strokes description of gauge transformations, read [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory).

Comment: Could you give me another hint for a good choice of $\xi$?

Comment: A particular form for $\xi$ is not even necessary. First insert $\xi$ into the curl, then choose its partial derivatives so that some parts of the curl are forced to zero. You'll be left with a reduced set of PDEs that are trivial to solve. 
Anything else would be giving away the answer!